# Como pegar o nome da ultima div pai com parents?

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma sequencia de divs como as de baixo.

```
<div class="upage" id="id01">
 <div class="main" id="id02">
   <div class="main2" id="id03">
   </div>   
 </div>
</div>
```

Preciso pegar o id da classe que está acima neste caso deveria retorna `id01`.
Utilizo o `parents(".upage");` porem ele me vem um apontador com a div toda. preciso pegar apenas o ID.

Como fazer ?

Comment: Qual é o elemento ponto de partida? Talvez o `closest()` seja o melhor? `.closest('.upage').attr('id');`

Comment: O ponto de partida é um input com focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro usares o `.closest()` que recebe um argumento que pode ser uma classe. Seguidamente o `attr('id')` que vai buscar a ID do elemento que o `.closest()` retornou.

```
$('input').on('focus', function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('.upage').attr('id');
    // fazer algo com o id
});
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/gby3944g/